# cpu load in multi core multi processors

Tags: linux, operating-system, cpu

I am searching to understand the relation between multi core multi processors systems and cpu load? As I searched before "On multi-processor system, the load is relative to the number of processor available".
I have a server with 4 processors each of them is quad-core, I want to know the threshold of traffic for this system. Is it 16 or not?? 
the OS is redhat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly - yes, but in general - a bit smaller. The problem is that each processor has its own memory controller with memory attached to it. While the memory of each processor is accessible from other processors this access speed is lower than to the memory attached directly to the processor's memory controller. The same applies to the PCI devices - they are 'close enough' to one processor, and some more time is required to access this device from the other processors.

Thus, when you set affinity of some threads in your application, for example, you should clearly understand that you do not push this thread to the other processor as this pinning may actually degrade the performance of your process.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of traffic are we talking about? Web traffic? If so, your serve capacity will vary depending on the profile of the service it is hosting. To find true capacity you will need to perform a load test. There are many tools out there to help you with this.

In addition, 4 quad-core processors is equals to 16 cores (or CPU's).